# Get usb hardware or instance id using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, operating-system, hardware

I'am trying to get usb mass storage instance id for eject usb using devcon from last 2 days but not able to get that. I have tried alot of solutions but still failed.

```
  ManagementObject dsk = new ManagementObject(@"win32_logicaldisk.deviceid=""j:""");
    dsk.Get();
    string id = dsk["VolumeSerialNumber"].ToString(); 
    Console.WriteLine(id);
```

It returns instance id. when i pass this id to devcon it doesnt remove any device. Passing id to devcon in this way

```
Devcon remove usbstor\deviceID
```

is there any way to remove usb using device name as like G, H or I etc or get required instance id.
Any help will be appricated.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling UAC and also running devcon.exe under Administrator credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I think *#usblib* can be helpfull for you , it allow you to play around usb divices [#usblib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpUSBLib/default.aspx)